# Flutter : create new instance of a class which no have default constructor and change some properties

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class with name "RecognisedText" in one of my packages which is required in my Flutter application. This class is:

```
class RecognisedText {
  RecognisedText._(this.text, this.blocks);

  factory RecognisedText.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    var resText = map["text"];
    var textBlocks = <TextBlock>[];
    for (var block in map["blocks"]) {
      var textBlock = TextBlock.fromMap(block);
      textBlocks.add(textBlock);
    }
    return RecognisedText._(resText, textBlocks);
  }

  ///String containing all the text identified in a image.
  final String text;

  ///All the blocks of text present in image.
  final List<TextBlock> blocks;
}
```

I want to define a variable from this class:

```
RecognisedText myobject = RecognisedText(mytext,myblocks);
```

but it raise this error:

```
The class 'RecognisedText' doesn't have a default constructor
```

I tried to define myobject in different way:

```
RecognisedText myobject;
myobject.text = mytext;
myobject.blocks = myblocks;
```

but it raise this error:

```
'text' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
```

How i can define my new variable from **RecognisedText** class and set properties? I can't change any part of class **RecognisedText** because it is a remote class (added from **pubspec.yaml**)

**Edit:**
I finally solved my problem with this code:

```
RecognisedText myobject = RecognisedText.fromMap({"text": mytext, "blocks": myblocks});
```

Comment: You have to use the `fromMap` factory.

Comment: you can't do that because it's a private constructor

Comment: I used : **RecognisedText myobject = RecognisedText.fromMap(mytext,myblocks)** but error occured:  **The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Class can't create its instance so try using YourClassName.fromMap constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Class **RecognisedText** is designed in the way that you can not create its instance other than using its **fromMap** constructor, which accepts map.

So the only way to create it is to create map with values you need and pass it to **RecognisedText.fromMap** constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your block and your text as variables, you can modify you class like this to accept a default constructor :

```
class RecognisedText {
  //----Replace this line ----
  //RecognisedText._(this.text, this.blocks);
  //----By this line ----
  RecognisedText.(this.text, this.blocks);

  factory RecognisedText.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    var resText = map["text"];
    var textBlocks = <TextBlock>[];
    for (var block in map["blocks"]) {
      var textBlock = TextBlock.fromMap(block);
      textBlocks.add(textBlock);
    }
    return RecognisedText._(resText, textBlocks);
  }

  ///String containing all the text identified in a image.
  final String text;

  ///All the blocks of text present in image.
  final List<TextBlock> blocks;
}
```

To complete Alex's answer, the constructor fromMap takes a map as a parameter. It should look like :

```
RecogniserdText.fromMap({'text': myText, 'blocks': myblock1, 'blocks': myblock2, 'blocks': myblock3});
```